# Regex matching certain number of characters + regex with roman numerals

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract names of genes and chromosomes from the lines of user's input. Lines are like this:

> YAL002W VPS8 SGDID:S000000002, Chr I from 143707-147531, 
>           Genome Release 64-2-1

Gene name is the second "word" in the line (= 3 capital letters from A to Z followed by a number from 0 to 9)  Chromosomes are 'Chr' followed by roman numerals. I am trying to use regex to do this.

I am trying to use regex to do this.

This is the part of my code.

```
 import sys
 import re 

 sequence = sys.stdin.readlines()
 ref_d = {}
 temp_genename = None 
 temp_chrname = None 

 genename_pattern = '^([A-Z]{3})([0-9]{1})$'
 chr_pattern = 'Chr (?=[MDCLXVI)M*(C[MD]|D?C*)(X[CL]|L?X*)(I[XV]|V?|*)$

 m1 = re.search(genename_pattern, sequence)
 m2 = re.search(chr_pattern, sequence)

 print(m1.group())
 print(m2.group())
```

From the input above I want my code to return m1 = VPS8 and m2 = Chr I. However, it keeps on returning:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: I believe it should be of type SearchObj but it keeps on returning this error

Comment: I just tried your code, `m1` returns `None` meaning no match, `m2` throws an error on `chr_pattern` `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import re


sequence = "YAL002W VPS8 SGDID:S000000002, Chr I from 143707-147531, Genome Release 64-2-1"

genename_pattern = r'\b([A-Z]{3}\d)\b'  #Upper Case 3 letters, single digit. 
chr_pattern = 'Chr\s+(.*?)\s+'          #Get string after Chr until space

m1 = re.search(genename_pattern, sequence)
m2 = re.search(chr_pattern, sequence)

print(m1.group(1))
print(m2.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
VPS8
I
```